# Stackview doesn't append second view

Tags: ios, view, swift3, uiscrollview, xcode8

I've created a stack view programmatically and I added a view which I've created programmatically too to it. But when I try to add a second view it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var codingScrollView: UIView!
let codeStackView = UIStackView()
var codeViews = [CodeView]()
let codeView1 = CodeView(name: "Lennart", date: "13/05/2002", code: "Just some code")
let codeView2 = CodeView(name: "Nina", date: "01/07/1999", code: "Also some code")
```

The codingScrollView is the contentview I've added to a UIScrollView.
The codeStackView is the one I've described before
The codeViews array is being used to add the views to the stackview.

Here's the viewDidLoad method:

```
    codeViews.append(codeView1)
    codeViews.append(codeView2)

    codingScrollView.addSubview(codeStackView)
    codingScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 226/255, green: 226/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1)

    codeStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codingScrollView.centerXAnchor)
    codeStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codingScrollView.centerYAnchor)

    codeStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    codeStackView.spacing = 10

    codeStackView.axis = .horizontal
    codeStackView.alignment = .center

    for i in 0...codeViews.count - 1 {
        codeStackView.addSubview(codeViews[i])
        codeStackView.addArrangedSubview(codeViews[i])
    }
```

But if I run the app it won't show the second view, it only shows one of them.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the codeView{1,2} to the stack view first then add the `codeStackView` to the `codingScrollView`.

Also, be sure to set `codeStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` before doing any constraints.

```
codeViews.append(codeView1)
codeViews.append(codeView2)

for i in 0...codeViews.count - 1 {
    codeStackView.addSubview(codeViews[i])
    codeStackView.addArrangedSubview(codeViews[i])
}

codeStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

codeStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codingScrollView.centerXAnchor)
codeStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codingScrollView.centerYAnchor)

codeStackView.spacing = 10

codeStackView.axis = .horizontal
codeStackView.alignment = .center

codingScrollView.addSubview(codeStackView)
codingScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 226/255, green: 226/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: But the weird thing is that the stack view isn't centered at all